# Neo4j won't start on Windows 7 (ok on Windows 10)

Tags: neo4j

I've been experimenting with Neo4j Community Edition 3.4.6 on **Windows 10**... and all good.

But *Neo4j Community Edition 3.4.7* on **Windows 7** won't start!

When I issue the command `E:\neo4j\bin\neo4j console` from the Windows 7 Power Shell (E:\neo4j\ is where I installed neo4j), just like I did with no problem on Windows 10, it gives the following error message and quits:

> Invoke-Neo4j : Unable to determine the version of the installation at E:\neo4j
>
> At line:1 char:175
>
> - try { Unblock-File -Path 'E:\neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management*.*' -ErrorAction 'SilentlyContinue' > catch <>;Import-Module
>
> 'E:\neo4j\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4j <<<<  console)
>
> - CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
>
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j

On the Windows7 machine, I have the identical "Java SE Development Kit 8 Update 181 (64-bit)" installed as I have on the Windows 10.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's two things I'm thinking:

1. The files need to be Unblocked - this kind of depends on how you got the files on the machine. Easiest is to Right-Click on the `.zip/.exe` and select unblock, then unzip.
   I would do this as a matter of course, just to ensure it's not this that's causing the problem.
2. It's something to do with the Powershell version - I can't remember what Win7 has by default, I think it's 2.0 which *should* be ok, but then again, *should* is a famous last word (newest version is here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616 - and it says that works on Win7 SP1)

To try to work it out, I would go *manual PowerShell* --

Open up a Powershell window (as Admin) and navigate to the folder, then import the module (we'll bypass security first - just to give us the best chance):

```
>PS E:\neo4j>Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass
>PS E:\neo4j>Import-Module .\bin\Neo4j-Management.psd1 -verbose
```

Check the output of that - if you don't get any errors, try running:

```
>PS E:\neo4j>Invoke-Neo4j console
```

If that doesn't work - if you can update your question with the output from both the `Import-Module` and `Invoke-Neo4j` outputs, that would be great!